# Run Mythril tool using hardhat on contracts?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

1. Mythril fails to import remotely and all-time searches in the local file system - to solve this I used Hardhat to compile my contract - and hardhat compiled contract.
2. Now I am stuck on How to run Mythril on the contract using Hardhat to compile the solidity file.

```
npx hardhat compile // this comiles contract
myth -a FILENAME.sol --execution-timeout 10 //
```

***myth compiles file.sol using solc compiler and again gives import error - NOW HOW TO USE HARDHAT compiled solidity and RUN it on mythril.***

Answer (score 1):

### The Solc compiler fails to compile smart contracts with import statements, which is a known issue and a dead end.

During my research, where I am analyzing false positives reported by symbolic analysis tools such as Mythril or Manticore, I was able to find a way to compile and analyze all kinds of contracts without any hassle.

#### Solution:

- install hardhat [https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#installation]
- Place all your smart contracts in Hardhat's contracts repository.
- Run `npx hardhat compile` in Hardhat's contracts directory.
- Hardhat will compile all of your contracts and will place them in test directory
- Hardhat provides Bytecode plus Addresses of your compiled contracts.
- Now you can easily analyze your smart contracts on their bytecodes or addresses.
- For Mythril Address `myth a -a <address> --infura-id <INFURA API KEY> ---execution-time 3600`
- For Mythril Bytecode copy Bytecode and place in a file with extention .asm
- Run on Mythril Bytecode `myth a --bin -f <filename.asm> --execution-time 3600strong text`
- Get INFURA API KEY from their online site

#### You can easily get analysis using this method without any hassle also all of the contracts get compiled at once. It took 2 weeks of effort to find this method, and I was able to analyze and get all the vulnerabilities.

***Check my Research*** on Github
[a link](https://github.com/theAliHassan/EVALUATION-AND-DEVELOPMENT-OF-SMART-CONTRACT-ANALYSIS-TOOLS-IN-BLOCKCHAIN.git)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to what you're trying is that you could flatten your contract in order to run Mythril. That should give no import issues since all is in a single file.

I usually do this (for Slither and Mythril analysis) when I want to run a test on a single contract inside a big project, or when having similar import issues and don't want to spend too much time figuring out how to solve it.